# How can I remove a plastic flange from a 4 inch PVC pipe?

Tags: toilet, flange

Having an issue trying to remove a plastic flange from a 4 inch PVC pipe.  I tried cutting and chiseling it away.  It must have been cemented with a primer and cement.  Are there any other (simple) ways to remove the flange?  The top part is off I'm only dealing with the part that is left inside the PVC.

Comment: There is a specialty tool available which will line up a hole saw perfectly to the pipe and allow you to drill out the remainder of it. However, it may be cheaper to cut the pipe out and install a new piece and the flange.

Comment: Need photo need photo

Answer (score 2):

I've seen some discussion here of fancy plumber tools (a bit too expensive for the amount of use anyone **but** a plumber would put them to, unless you can find them in a rental store) that apply heat and grip/pull things apart.

Other than that (which I've never seen or used, only seen mentioned), I'm prone to consider PVC joints as forever, so the stock approach when you need a new one is to cut at a point where you can install a coupling, some new pipe (in most cases), and the new fitting.